# Progress block on one page checkout - JS Events

Tags: checkout, javascript

I am trying to modify behaviour of JavaScript handling progress block(right column) on Magento one page checkout.

There is an 'onclick' event attached directy to 'a' tag

```
<a onclick="checkout.changeSection('opc-billing'); return false;" href="#billing">Change</a>
```

I would like to add some code to onclick but can't find the `checkout` object with 'changeSection' method anywhere. In `opcheckout.js` there's a `Checkout` obj. - so it's not the same one.

Do you know, by any chance, how to find this object and method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track.
The `Checkout` defined in `opcheckout.js` is the one you are looking for.
That is a js class and `checkout` (with lowercase c) is an instance of that class.
The instance is created in `checkout/onepage.phtml`

```
var checkout = new Checkout(accordion,{
    progress: '<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/onepage/progress') ?>',
    review: '<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/onepage/review') ?>',
    saveMethod: '<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/onepage/saveMethod') ?>',
    failure: '<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/cart') ?>'}
);
```

So you can modify the function `changeSection` from `opcheckout.js`. I think you already know this, but just to be on the safe side, I'll say it.  Don't modify the file from the default theme. Copy it in your own theme first.

Comment: Many thanks Marius! It works as you described. Also, I use customized copy of opcheckout.js :).